# Can the theorem on semi-continuity of fiber dimension be explained as a semi-continuity of rank of a quasi-coherent sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Here are two theorems:

1. If $F$ is a finite type quasi-coherent sheaf on a scheme $X$, then $ \operatorname{rank}(F)(p) = \dim_{k(p)} F_p \otimes_{O_p} k(p)$ is a upper semicontinuous function on $X$.
2. If $\pi : X \to Y$ is a closed morphism of finite type $k$ schemes, then the dimension of the fiber over $q \in Y$ is an upper semicontinuous function on $Y$. (Also, the dimension of the largest component of the fiber containing $P \in X$ is an upper semicontinuous function on X.)

Are these related?

For a finite type sheaf $F$ on a reduced scheme X, it looks like a vector bundle on each of the locally closed subsets given by $\operatorname{rank} F = k$ for $k$ varying. So in this case my *guess* would be that there is a total space over $X$ for which $F$ is the sheaf of sections and the two theorems — in the case of a finite type reduced $k$-scheme — are saying the same thing here.

When is there a reasonable total space for a quasicoherent sheaf? (The étale space is not reasonable — it is way to big.)

Are they both special cases of something more general?

Why does upper semi-continuity of fibers appear so often?

Comment: In the statement about semicontinuity on $Y$ in the second theorem, you need properness (counterexample: consider an open immersion). See also [this question on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193/when-is-fiber-dimension-upper-semi-continuous) for a survey.

Comment: @Remy Thanks you are right, I forgot the closedness hypothesis. And thanks for the link.

Comment: Maybe something involving the sheaf of relative differentials?

Comment: @ElleNajt -there is a result (see Hartshorne Prop III.10.4) saying that if $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of non singular varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$, then $f$ is smooth of relative dimension $n$ iff $\Omega^1_{X/Y}$ is locally free of rank $n$. This is iff the fiber $\Omega^1_{X/Y}(x)$ has dimension $n$ over $\kappa(x)$, where $x$ is any point in $X$. Hence the relative cotangent sheaf gives information on the dimension of the fiber.